# How to fix TypeError in angular7

Tags: angular, typeerror

im having a problem trying to retrieve a type

That is the class:

```
book: Book;

[...]

getBooksDetails(id) {
    this.api.getBook(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.book = data;
        console.log(this.book);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        this.getBooksReviews(this.book.BookTitulo);
      });
  }

[...]

ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
    this.getBooksDetails(this.route.snapshot.params.id);

    console.log(this.currentUser.username);
    console.log(this.book.BookTitulo);

    this.reviewForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      body : [null, Validators.required],
      rating : [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Everything is fine until this line:

```
console.log(this.book.BookTitulo);
```

where i receive this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'BookTitulo' of undefined

I think that im assigning the result correctly in the method to the book object, please help and thanks for reading.

Comment: You are using `console.log(this.book.BookTitulo);` which will get executed even before your observable emits the value. Because of this reason this.book might not have value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use promise to return data from the method `getBooksDetails`, refer below code

```
getBooksDetails(id) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    this.api.getBook(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        res(data);
        this.book = data;
        console.log(this.book);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        this.getBooksReviews(this.book.BookTitulo);
      });

})  }


ngOnInit() {


    this.getBooksDetails(this.route.snapshot.params.id).then(data => {
       this.book = data;
       console.log(this.book.BookTitulo);
    });

  }
```

This might help you to fix the issue, let me know if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

OnInit happens synchronously, while a subscription is not synchronous. So it queries for data and waits while everything else happens.. And when it does, it gets in the queue of commands.

OnInit is synchronous so while the subscription is waiting for an answer, the console.log happens, and this.book is undefined.

If you add the console.log inside the subscribe you will see an answer. Any logic that has to happen after the subscription completes has to go inside the response of the subscribe.